# event-loop-stats NPM not installing in windows 10

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

when I installing [event-loop-stats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-loop-stats) npm in windows 10 environment 
Error is throwing. Anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
C:\Users\bane\Desktop\package_test\node_modules\event-loop-stats>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\devaraj
.c\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.2\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (
node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  eventLoopStats.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\users\bane\.node-gyp\6.11.2\include\node\uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No su
ch file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\eventLoopStats.cc) [C:\Users\bane\Desktop\package_test\node_modules\eve
nt-loop-stats\build\eventLoopStats.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\bane\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp
\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bane\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\
\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bane\Desktop\package_test\node_modules\event-loop-stats
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

already installed npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

After install windows sdk 10

```
c:\users\bane\.node-gyp\6.11.2\include\node\uv-errno.h(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file or directory (compiling source fi
le ..\src\eventLoopStats.cc) [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\event-loop-stats\build\eventLoopStats.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory (compiling source fil
e C:\User\bane\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc) [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\event-loop-st
ats\build\eventLoopStats.vcxproj]
```

After configuring c++ path in environment variables

```
c:\users\devaraj.c\.node-gyp\6.11.2\include\node\uv-errno.h(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file
 or directory (compiling source file ..\src\eventLoopStats.cc) [C:\Users\devaraj.c\Desktop\package_test\node_modules\event-loop-stats
\build\eventLoopStats.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file
or directory (compiling source file C:\Users\devaraj.c\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_del
ay_load_hook.cc) [C:\Users\devaraj.c\Desktop\package_test\node_modules\event-loop-stats\build\eventLoopStats.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Try install [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Okay, now I'm installing windows sdk 10 version

Comment: I ll let you know the results

Comment: Installed windows 10 sdk but same error is throwing

Comment: The error `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h'` is throwing too?

Comment: It throwing errno.h and ctype.h file is missing, After installed sdk 10

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @svm C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140 This is my compiler version

Comment: On your cl line, add this flag pointing it to the location of the headers: `-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt"`

Comment: Also try set `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`

Comment: Yes I will try now

Comment: where & how should I set this path? "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt". I dont have an idea :(

Comment: Try add this path to the Environment Variables as `PATH`

Comment: I added path in environment variable but still facing the same error